# Is there a way to list an unknown number of elements in json using python?

Tags: python, json

So i am trying to get elements in a json listed but i don't know how many there will be, depending on the tag.

i tried this:

```py
tag = "cat"
r = requests.get('https://danbooru.donmai.us/related_tag.json?query=' + tag)
j = json.loads(r.text)
dump = json.dumps(j, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
taglist = []
taglist.append(j["wiki_page_tags"][all][0])
if tag in dump:
    print(f"{taglist}")
```

and i'm trying to get a result that looks like that

```
tag1
tag2
tag3
```

sorry for that trash code, thanks for your help

Comment: Can you give an example of the json output you want to process, the output that your code currently has, and what you've tried to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

```
print('\n'.join([x[0] for x in j["wiki_page_tags"]]))
```

Full example:

```
import requests
import json

tag = "cat"
r = requests.get('https://danbooru.donmai.us/related_tag.json?query=' + tag)
j = json.loads(r.text)
dump = json.dumps(j, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
taglist = [x[0] for x in j["wiki_page_tags"]]
print('\n'.join(taglist))
```

prints:

```
stuffed_animal
cathead
cheetah
leopard
lion
panther
serval
tiger
black_cat
white_cat
calico
siamese_cat
kitten
cat_focus
too_many_cats
```